# How to detect data available on any communication channel?

Tags: c, multithreading, select, io, libuv

Motivation:

I am writing an application handling all possible communication channels
in a uniform way, that is input/output via terminal, serial interface,
graphical user interface (xcb | win32), web interface via sockets.

Question:

I need some mechanism to:
a) make my main application loop sleep or block (to save cpu time);
b) wake it up again as soon as data arrive on any of the channels.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:

1 blocking call:

- function: blocks the program on just one channel
- problem: data arriving on other channels cannot be detected
- example: xcb_wait_for_event, fgetwc

2 non-blocking call:

- function: tests/reads all channels in an endless loop
- problem: cpu usage (busy waiting)
- problem: does not detect all input if loop is faster than user
- example: xcb_poll_for_event, fgetwc with termios settings ~ICANON; ~ECHO; c_cc[VMIN] = 0; c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

3 select:

- function: avoids busy waiting and covers many channels
- problem: handles only those channels with file descriptor (not xcb etc.)

4 libuv (from Node.js):

- function: handles multiple channels, event-driven asynchronous i/o model
- problem: does not handle graphical windowing system events
- problem: forces me to use their data structures
- problem: dependency on external library

5 one thread per channel and sleep:

- function: does detect data and may set an internal flag
- problem: the main loop needs to check the flag (busy waiting, cpu usage)

6 one thread per channel and pause or sigsuspend and system signal to wake up:

- function: like sleep but avoiding busy waiting using system signal to wake up
- problem: the process's threads are sleeping as well and cannot detect input
- problem: if running multiple instances of my program, all will be woken up